# CiviVolunteer on 4.6.5: Error while enabling volunteer management on event

Tags: civievent, civivolunteer

When I enable volunteer management with the form "volunteer signup", I get the error shown in the image.

[image]

I tried reinstalling CiviVolunteer but now get this error:

[image]

Might be related with this issue:

[Error while installing CiviVolunteer on civicrm 4.6.5](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/error-while-installing-civivolunteer-on-civicrm-4-6-5/4254#4254)

Comment: Has this worked in the past, and this just started occurring? Or is this your first time trying to enable volunteering for an event?

Comment: It's the first time I try to enable volunteering for an event.

Comment: For some reason, it looks like the extension didn't install some required tables. Can you try an uninstall and reinstall?